# vim "set property" to a file and then use it with Project navigation

Tags: vim, navigation, project-navigator

I use vim for programming. my current job based on Yii MVC framework.

When you work with MVC framework, you are always navigating among models, controllers and views. I want to make save time navigation for my tasks.

The first is: i want jump to a model related controller. One model could have one controller for jumping to. Which i want to setup once in a project.

What is the best solution for this ?

My opinion is create a comment in a model header like phpDoc

```
/*
* @controller ControllerName
*/
```

And then write a vim function, which will find "ControllerName" in current file and open this file. Then bind it to a key combination.

What is your idea to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is known as tag navigation. Chances are that your fileformat is already supported by the omnipresent **[*exuberant ctags*](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)** (guessing it is php, for sure).

Then you'd basically do:

```
:!ctags -R .
:tj ControllerName
```

You can use tab-completion (`Control` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>), do searches (`:tj /troll` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Ctags has numerous options to enrich/limit the kinds of objects tagged. To selectively act on certain files only:

```
:tags +=controllertags
:!ctags -o controllertags **/*Controller.php
```

which will tag only controller sources in a separate tags file so you can keep working with the rest of your tags setup as before (in case you were already using it for other stuff)

Comment: you right, i can to fast jumping to a any tag with ctags, but now i have at least 20 controllers and it's alot of keys for typing (eveng with tab completition) when im juping. Therefore i want to describe a model-controller relation once, and then just pressing a one key combination,i will jump to my defined controller.

Comment: you could find some inspiration in the implementation of the 'standard' _alternate_ script ([a.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31))

Comment: for controllertags solution, how can i search tags only under controller tags ?

Comment: @RusAlex: you can't directly. However, you can define a function that saves the value of `tags`, sets `tags=controllertags`, executes the tag search, and restores the `tags` setting. Then map a command/key to call the function